# convert to nested format php

Tags: php, laravel-5, nested, laravel-5.1

I just want some help in displaying the correct structure of the image data below. Basically what i want is to display it in nested form. From the data below, I would like it to display like this:

- Engel (parent which parent_id = 0)

  - Chest Fridge - Freezers

    - Small Engel
    - digital platinum
  - Upright Fridge

    - Built-in fridge
  - Fridge Accessories

    - Blankets
    - Carry handles

[image]

I hope anyone can help me. Im using php fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it recursively

```
// For example, data fetched from database:
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'sku' => 'name1', 'parent_id' => null],
    ['id' => 2, 'sku' => 'name12', 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'sku' => 'name12', 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id' => 4, 'sku' => 'name2', 'parent_id' => null],
    ['id' => 5, 'sku' => 'name123', 'parent_id' => 2],
];

// Recursive function
function outTree($data, $parentId = null) {
    $str = '';
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $str .= '<li>' . $row['sku'];
            $str .= outTree($data, $row['id']);
            $str .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    if ($str) {
        $str = '<ul>' . $str . '</ul>';
    }
    return $str;
}

echo outTree($data);
```